# How to use Angular ng-start, ng-end, ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've seen examples of using ng-start to pass data throughout the entire html page.  How do I pass result.name to the second div?  Example below.

```
      <tr ng-repeat="result in results">

      <td ng-click='showCars(result.cars);'>{{result.Name}}</td>
                <td>{{result.Address}}</td>
                <td>{{result.Phone}}</td>
                <td>{{result.Status}}</td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    <br>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Car</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>ResultStatus</th>
        </tr>
        <!--<tr ng-repeat="car in result.cars">-->
        <tr ng-repeat="car in cars">
            <td>{{car.Make}}</td>
            <td>{{car.Year}}</td>
            <td>{{result.Status}}</td>
```

Search for April then click Name column to populate the form...
Here's [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/o4RpnMz6cWBiXHPSk8UX?p=preview)!

Comment: you miss a in : <div ng-repeat="car in result.cars">

Comment: demo code is different than code in question. It doesn't have any nested repeats and not clear what demo is supposed to do. Doesn't display anything other than top box

Comment: Sorry that is a typo.  I tried car in result.cars.  See here http://plnkr.co/edit/o4RpnMz6cWBiXHPSk8UX?p=preview  I commented out start and end.

Comment: Type April, click search, then click the name to see form populate.  I've added the nested ng-repeats to the question.

Answer (score 0):

In AngularJS 1.2, ng-repeat now supports multiple elements with the ng-repeat-start directive.

`<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl as app”>
  <div ng-repeat-start="thing in app.things">{{ thing }}</div>
  <div ng-repeat-end=""></div>
</body>`

The directive will iterate through app.things, and create these two sets of `<div>` elements for each thing.
The binding works normally, regardless of where it appears within the directive:

`<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl as app">
  <div ng-repeat-start="thing in app.things">{{ thing }}</div>
  Anything in here
  <div ng-repeat-end="">Also in here with binding {{ thing }}</div>
</body>`

As long as the **elements containing the ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end directives are sibling elements, everything will operate correctly**.

The following **example**, with the ng-repeat-end in a child element, **will not work**:

`<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl as app">
  <div ng-repeat-start="thing in app.things">{{ thing }}</div>
  Anything in here
  <div><div ng-repeat-end="">Also in here with binding {{ thing }}</div></div>
</body>`

Try here for reference : [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)